# List gets changed when Scope gets changed

Tags: python, list

When I append List in a for loop it changes it value correctly
and when I print it outside for loop it's value gets changed

```
arr=[]
b=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
for i in range(0,len(b)):
 b[i]=0
 arr.append(b)
 print(arr[i])
```

Here output is

```
 [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
 [0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
 [0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6, 7]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

---

And here

```
arr=[]
b=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
for i in range(0,len(b)):
 b[i]=0
 arr.append(b)
print(arr)
```

Output is

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Why the value of list gets changed ?

Comment: You are appending the same list to `arr`, i.e. every list inside `arr` is actually a reference to the same list. Then when you set a new value to zero on each iteration, you are modifying every list in `arr` simultaneously. You don't see this when printing in your loop because you aren't looking at the whole `arr`.

Comment: Also, the `for` loop is not creating a new scope. Its contents are in the same scope as the code outside.

Comment: Is there any solution for this ,I don't want the list to get changed?

Comment: @aniketdhole don't change the list, then. **It's the same list**. You probably meant to make a copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On each iteration, you are adding a reference to the same list `b` to your `arr`, which means that when you later set new values to zero, you are modifying all of the lists inside `arr` simultaneously. To avoid this, you can append a copy of `b` to `arr` instead by using `list(b)`, i.e.:

```
arr = []
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
for i in range(len(b)):
   b[i] = 0
   arr.append(list(b))
print(arr)
```

This outputs:

```
[[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6, 7], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```